# Terminology for a monoid $H$ s.t. $xy \in H^\times$ only if $x, y \in H^\times$

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids, factorization-theory

The title has it all. Is there any consolidated terminology for referring to a (multiplicative) monoid $H$ such that $xy \in H^\times$ (if and) only if $x, y \in H^\times$? Here is a short list of monoids with this property:

- Commutative monoids.
- [Unit-cancellative](https://mathoverflow.net/a/259790/16537) monoids (so, in particular, cancellative monoids).
- Monoids with at least one atom/irreducible element (as [proved by Benjamin Steinberg](https://mathoverflow.net/a/261870/16537)).

Incidentally, the three classes of monoids from this list have, of course, non-empty intersection, but none of them is contained in the union of the others.

*Edit.* In a previous version of this post, I was writing that the property in the title holds if $H^\times = \{1_H\}$ (i.e., for reduced monoids). That's not true, as can be seen by looking at $\langle x, y \mid xy = 1 \rangle$.

Comment: These are monoids that do not contain the bicycling monoid as a submonoid.

Comment: I hope you'll forgive my ignorance, what is the bicycling monoid? A Google search didn't help me much. *Edit.* OK, I guess you mean the bicyclic monoid from p. 32 in the 2003 reprint of Howie's *Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory*.

Comment: Sorry my phone changed bicyclic to bicycling

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct term is Dedekind finite. A monoid is Dedekind finite of $xy=1$ implies $yx=1$. This is clearly equivalent to your condition.

Comment: Cool. In particular, if $xy \in H^\times$ for some $x, y \in H$, then there exists $z \in H$ for which $xyz = zxy =1_H$. So, if $H$ is Dedekind-finite, then $yzx = 1_H$, hence $x$ and $y$ are invertible.