# Weak ideal systems $r$ for which the $r$-coheight satisfies a kind of triangle inequality

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids, prime-ideals, factorization-theory

Let $H$ be a multiplicatively written, commutative monoid with identity $1_H$, and let $\mathcal P(H)$ be the power set of $H$. If $X, Y \subseteq H$, we will set $$XY := \{xy: x \in X,\, y \in Y\}.$$
A *weak ideal system* on $H$ is a function $r: \mathcal P(H) \to \mathcal P(H)$ such that, for all $a \in H$ and $X, Y \subseteq H$, the following hold (given $V \subseteq H$, we will use $V_r$ in place of $r(V)$):

1. $\emptyset = \emptyset_r$ and $X \subseteq X_r$.
2. $X \subseteq Y_r$ implies $X_r \subseteq Y_r$.
3. $aH \subseteq \{a\}_r$.
4. $a X_r \subseteq (aX)_r$.

In particular, $r$ is named an *ideal system* if the last condition holds as an equality.

Weak ideal systems are reminiscent of [closure operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator), and have a rich and far-reaching theory, which grew up from intuitions and pioneering work of W. Krull and H. Prüfer, and is well documented by M.D. Larsen and P.J. McCarthy's book *Multiplicative Theory of Ideals* and R. Gilmer's *Multiplicative Ideal Theory*. If asked for a neat and lucid treatment of the subject, I would go for F. Halter-Koch's 1998 monograph *Ideal Systems: An Introduction to Multiplicative Ideal Theory*, with the caveat that weak ideal systems are defined therein in a "slightly" different way than we're doing: In Halter-Koch's book, the theory of [weak] ideal systems is developed by assuming that monoids have an absorbing element $0_H \ne 1_H$, and the first condition in the above list is replaced with $X \cup \{0_H\} \subseteq X_r$.

With this in mind, let $r$ be a weak ideal system on $H$. We say that a set $I \subseteq H$ is an *$r$-ideal* if $I = I_r$: If $H$ is the multiplicative monoid of a commutative unital ring $R$, then the function $$d: \mathcal P(H) \to \mathcal P(H): X \mapsto \{a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_n x_n: a_1, \ldots, a_n \in H, \, x_1, \ldots, x_n \in X\}$$ is an ideal system on $H$, and the $d$-ideals of $H$ are nothing but the good, old, classical ideals of $R$.

We denote by $\mathcal I_r(H)$ the set of $r$-ideals of $H$, which is made into a commutative, reduced monoid (this is simple, but not obvious) by the binary operation $$\cdot_r: \mathcal I_r(H) \times \mathcal I_r(H) \to \mathcal I_r(H): (I, J) \mapsto (IJ)_r,$$
referred to as *$r$-multiplication*. Note that $H$ and $\emptyset$ are $r$-ideals, and they serve, respectively, as the identity and the absorbing element of $\mathcal I_r(H)$.
An $r$-ideal $I$ of $H$ is termed a *prime $r$-ideal* if $I \ne H$ and $H \setminus I$ is a subsemigroup of $H$. In particular, the set of all prime $r$-ideals of $H$ is denoted by $r\text{-spec}(H)$ and called the *$r$-spectrum* of $H$.

If $I \in \mathcal I_r(H)$, we take $\text{coht}_r(I)$ to be the supremum of all $n \in \mathbf N^+$ for which there exist $\mathfrak p_1, \ldots, \mathfrak p_n \in r\text{-spec}(H)$ such that $\mathfrak p_{i-1} \subsetneq \mathfrak p_i$ for each $i \in [\![1, n]\!]$, where $\mathfrak p_0 := I$ and $\sup \emptyset := 0$. We call $\text{coht}_r(I)$ the *$r$-coheight* of $I$. It is straightforward that $\text{coht}_r(H) = 0$ and $\text{coht}_r(I) \le \text{coht}_r(J)$ for all $I, J \in \mathcal I_r(H)$ with $J \subseteq I$, and my question is:

> **Q.** Is there any (non-trivial) characterization of the pairs $(H, r)$ which verify the triangle inequality, i.e., such that $\text{coht}_r(I \cdot_r J) \le 1 + \text{coht}_r(I) + \text{coht}_r(J)$ for all $I, J \in \mathcal I_r(H) \setminus \{H\}$?

I don't know of a *single* example in which the inequality is *not* satisfied, but I must also confess that I've not tried too hard to find one. On a positive note, it's not too difficult to prove that the inequality holds (even without the "1 + " on the right-hand side) in the (very) extremal cases when:

- $H$ is arbitrary and $r$ is the *discrete weak ideal system* on $H$ (that is, the unique weak ideal system for which $X_r = H$ for every non-empty $X \subseteq H$);
- $H$ is a [null monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_semigroup) (i.e., there is a distinguished element $0_H \in H$ such that $xy = 0_H$ for all $x, y \in H \setminus \{1_H\}$) and $r$ is the fundamental ideal system determined by taking $X_r = XH$ for all $X \subseteq H$ (this is often called the *$s$-system*, and the corresponding ideals are precisely the ideals of $H$ in the usual sense of semigroup theory).

In addition, I *suspect* that the inequality is true when $H$ is the multiplicative monoid of a PID (which is, in a way, another extremal case), and can prove it in some special instances.

---

*Edit 1.* After discussing the question with Paolo Leonetti, I changed my mind and added a "1 + " on the right-hand side of the triangular inequality. In hindsight, this has a "natural justification", as we'd like to have a function $\mathcal I_r(H) \to \mathbf N \cup \{\infty\}$ which "separates" $H$ (namely, the only unit of $\mathcal I_r(H)$) from the $r$-prime ideals. But that wouldn't be (always) the case with the $r$-coheight, as confirmed by the following example (due to Paolo): Consider the monoid $(\mathbf N, +)$ with the unique ideal system $r$ for which $X_r = \mathbf N_{\ge \min X}$ for every non-empty $X \subseteq \mathbf N$. Then observe that the $r$-ideals are all and only the subsets of $\mathbf N$ of the form $\mathbf N_{\ge \kappa}$ with $\kappa \in \mathbf N \cup \{\infty\}$, and the unique prime $r$-ideals are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbf N^+$. Accordingly, ${\rm coht}_r(\mathbf N^+) = 0$, and this implies that the inequality without the "1 + " is false, by taking $I = J = \mathbf N^+$.

---

*Edit 2.* Here is a more conceptual counterexample to the inequality without the "1 + ": Let $H$ be a non-trivial, Dedekind-finite, commutative, reduced monoid with a non-empty set of atoms (e.g., $H$ may be the multiplicative monoid of the integers), take $r$ to be the $s$-ideal system mentioned in the above (i.e., $X_r := XH$ for every $X \subseteq H$), and set $I := H \setminus \{1_H\}$. We claim that $I$ is a prime $r$-ideal of $H$: Indeed, $IH \subsetneq H$, otherwise there would exist $x, y \in I$ such that $xy = 1_H$, which is impossible by an [observation of Benjamin Steinberg](https://mathoverflow.net/a/262001/16537) and the assumption that $H$ is reduced. It follows that $I$ is an $r$-ideal of $H$, and is actually a prime $r$-ideal, because its complement in $H$ is the trivial subgroup of $H$. So $\text{coht}_r(I) = 0$, while ${\rm coht}_r(I^2) \ge 1$, since $I^2 \subsetneq I$ by the fact that $H$ has no non-trivial unit and the set of atoms of $H$ is non-empty.

---

*Notes.* A monoid $H$ is *Dedekind-finite* if $xy=1_H$, for some $x, y \in H$, implies $yx=1_H$, and *reduced* if the only unit (or invertible element) of $H$ is the identity $1_H$. Finally, an *atom* of $H$ is a non-unit element $a \in H$ for which there don't exist two other non-unit elements $x, y \in H$ such that $a = xy$.

Comment: A related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267977/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality in the OP is true, and even in a stronger form: I'm indebted to Andrea Gagna for his [enlightening answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267943/), which has greatly inspired the following proofs.

**Proposition.** Assume $H$ is a commutative monoid and $r$ a weak ideal system on $H$, and let $I, J \in \mathcal I_r(H)$ and $\mathfrak p \in r\text{-spec}_r(H)$. The following hold:

$\phantom{iii}$(i) If $I \cdot_r J \subseteq \mathfrak p$, then $I \subseteq \mathfrak p$ or $J \subseteq \mathfrak p$.

$\phantom{iii}$(ii) $\text{coht}_r(I \cdot_r J) \le 1 + \max(\text{coht}_r(I), \text{coht}_r(J))$.

*Proof.* (i) Suppose $I \cdot_r J \subseteq \mathfrak p$. By the very definition of the $r$-multiplication and condition 1 in the axiomatic definition of a weak ideal system, we have 
$$IJ \subseteq (IJ)_r = I \cdot_r J \subseteq \mathfrak p.$$
If $I \subseteq \mathfrak p$, we are done. Otherwise, pick $x \in I \setminus \mathfrak p$. Then $xy \in \mathfrak p$ for every $y \in J$, and this implies $J \subseteq \mathfrak p$, because $H \setminus \mathfrak p$ is a subsemigroup of $H$ (by the assumption that $\mathfrak p$ is a prime $r$-ideal), so the existence of an element $y \in J \setminus \mathfrak p$ would yield $xy \in H \setminus \mathfrak p$ (since $x \in H \setminus \mathfrak p$), a contradiction.

(ii) The claim is obvious if the $r$-coheight of $I \cdot_r J$ is zero. Otherwise, let $\mathfrak p_1, \ldots, \mathfrak p_n$ be $r$-prime ideals such that $\mathfrak p_{i-1} \subsetneq \mathfrak p_i$ for each $i \in [\![1, n]\!]$, where $\mathfrak p_0 := I \cdot_r J$ for convenience. Then (i) implies (by symmetry) $I \subseteq \mathfrak p_1$. This shows that $n-1 \le \text{coht}_r(I)$, and the rest is clear. []

Answer (score 2):

The case of the ideal system $d$ (on the multiplicative monoid of a commutative ring $A$) defined in the OP has a positive answer. In fact, the answer we get is rather strong and it is an immediate consequence of the following basic result.

**Lemma. $-$** Let $A$ be a commutative unital ring, $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ two ideals and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal of $A$. If $\mathfrak{p}$ contains $\mathfrak{a}\cdot_d\mathfrak{b}$, then the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ contains one among $\mathfrak{a}$ or $\mathfrak{b}$.

*Proof.* Suppose $\mathfrak{p}$ does not contain either $\mathfrak{a}$ or $\mathfrak{b}$. That is to say, there exist elements $x$ in $\mathfrak{a}$ and $y$ in $\mathfrak{b}$ such that $x$ and $y$ do not belong to $\mathfrak{p}$. Therefore $xy$ is not in $\mathfrak{p}$, as this is a prime ideal. Hence $\mathfrak{p}$ does not contain the product $\mathfrak{a}\cdot_d\mathfrak{b}$ and we get a contradiction.

*Edit.* Since I misread he definition of ideal in first place and it does not coincide with what I had in mind, I'd like to add some words about it and fix the proposition (see the comments).

**Remarks.** Notice that for any ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of $A$, the value of $\text{coht}_d(\mathfrak{a})$ is precisely $\text{dim}(A/\mathfrak{a})$, the [Krull dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) of $A/\mathfrak{a}$, when $\mathfrak{a}$ is a prime ideal and it is equal to $\text{dim}(A/\mathfrak{a}) + 1$ otherwise.

**Proposition. $-$** Let $A$ be a commutative unital ring and $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ two ideals of $A$. Then
$$\text{coht}_d(\mathfrak{a}\cdot_d\mathfrak{b}) \leq 1 + \text{max}\{\text{coht}_d(\mathfrak{a}), \text{coht}_d(\mathfrak{b})\}.$$

*Proof.* We can restrict to the case in which the $d$-coheights of the two ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ are finite, the result being trivial otherwise. The previous lemma gives us the relation
$$\text{dim}(A/\mathfrak{a}\cdot_d\mathfrak{b}) = \text{max}\{\text{dim}(A/\mathfrak{a}), \text{dim}(A/\mathfrak{b})\}.$$
Indeed, suppose wlog $n = \text{dim}(A/\mathfrak{a})\geq \text{dim}(A/\mathfrak{b})$ and consider a strict maximal chain of prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_0 \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}_1 \subsetneq \dots \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}_n$ of $A$, $n\geq 0$, such that $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq \mathfrak{p}_0$. If we had a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ satisfying the relation $\mathfrak{a}\cdot_d \mathfrak{b} \subseteq \mathfrak{q} \subsetneq p_0$, the lemma would imply either $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq \mathfrak{q}$ or $\mathfrak{b}\subseteq \mathfrak{q}$, therefore producing a chain of primes over $\mathfrak{a}$ (resp. over $\mathfrak{b}$) of length $n+2$, which is impossible by assumption. The considerations of the above remark then immediately give the inequality regarding the $d$-coheights.

Comment: Doesn't the lemma in your answer prove only that $\text{coht}_d(\mathfrak a \cdot_d \mathfrak b) \le 1+ \max(\text{coht}_d(\mathfrak a), \text{coht}_d(\mathfrak b))$? The claim is obvious if the $d$-coheight of $\mathfrak a \cdot_d \mathfrak b$ is zero. Otherwise, let $\mathfrak p_1,\ldots,\mathfrak p_n$ be $d$-prime ideals s.t. $\mathfrak p_{i-1}\subsetneq\mathfrak p_i$ for each $i\in [\![1,n]\!]$, where $\mathfrak p_0:=\mathfrak a\cdot_d\mathfrak b$. Then the lemma in your answer implies, wlog, $\mathfrak a\subseteq\mathfrak p_1$: Note that we started with a *strict* inclusion, but (...)

Comment: (...) we end up with a *weak* inclusion. This yields $n-1 \le \text{coht}_d(\mathfrak a)$, and we're done. [] (In any case, the main conclusion is still correct: The inequality in the OP holds true for the ideal system $d$ of the multiplicative monoid of *any* commutative, unital ring.)

Comment: Btw, the inequality $\text{coht}_d(\mathfrak a\cdot_d \mathfrak b) \le 1+\max(\text{coht}_d(\mathfrak a),\text{coht}_d(\mathfrak b))$ cannot be improved, in general: In your notations, if $A$ is the ring of integers and $\mathfrak a = \mathfrak b = \{np: n \in \mathbf Z\}$ for some prime element of $\mathbf N^+$, then $\text{coht}_d(\mathfrak a)=\text{coht}_d(\mathfrak a)=0$, but $\text{coht}_d(\mathfrak a \cdot_d \mathfrak b)=1$.