# Which monoids can be realized as the monoid of ideals of a commutative monoid?

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids, factorization-theory

Let $H$ be a commutative monoid (written multiplicatively). We say that a set $I \subseteq H$ is an *ideal* of $H$ if $IH = I$. The set $\mathcal I(H)$ of all ideals of $H$ is made into a (commutative) monoid by the binary operation 
$$
\mathcal I(H) \times \mathcal I(H) \to \mathcal I(H): (I, J) \mapsto IJ := \{xy: x \in I, \, y \in J\}.
$$
The identity is $H$, and $\mathcal I(H)$ is actually a non-trivial, *reduced* monoid with an absorbing element (namely, the empty set). (In this context, "reduced" means that there is no other unit besides the identity.) Then my question, which comes, at least in part, out of curiosity, is the following:

> **Q1.** Given a non-trivial, commutative, reduced monoid $K$ with an absorbing element, does there exist a commutative monoid $H$ such that $\mathcal I(H)$ is isomorphic to $K$? Has this realization problem been ever considered?

*Edit 1.* As an illustrative example, let us consider the case when $K$ is the (canonical) zeroification of the additive monoid of non-negative integers, that is, $K \cong_{\sf Mon} (\mathbf N \cup \{\infty\}, +)$. We want to find a commutative, reduced monoid $H$ such that $\mathcal I(H)$ is isomorphic to $K$. What could we try first? The most naif idea may be to start with $(\mathbf N, +)$. So, let's try first with this.

By definition, a *non-empty* set $I\subseteq \mathbf N$ is an ideal of $H = (\mathbf N, +)$ iff $$I = I+\mathbf N := \{x+n: x \in I, \, n \in \mathbf N\},$$ and this is possible iff $I$ is of the form $\mathbf N_{\ge k}$ for some $k \in \mathbf N$ (if there exists $n \in \mathbf N \setminus I$ such that $n \ge \min I$, then $\min I + (n - \min I) \in I + \mathbf N$, a contradiction). Consequently, we obtain
$$\mathcal I(H) = \bigl\{\mathbf N_{\ge \kappa}: \kappa \in \mathbf N \cup \{\infty\}\bigr\},$$
and it is now trivial to check that $\mathcal I(H)$ and $(\mathbf N \cup \{\infty\}, +)$ are isomorphic monoids.

*Edit 2.* Benjamin Steinberg [notes](https://mathoverflow.net/a/268125/16537) that the answer to Q1 is no, by observing that $\mathcal I(H)$ cannot realize any reduced, commutative monoid with an absorbing element embedding a non-trivial, finite group as a subsemigroup (e.g., the zeroification of the unconditional unitization of a non-trivial, finite, abelian group), because $I^{k+1} \subseteq I^k$ for all $I \in \mathcal I(H)$ and $k \in \mathbf N$. This leads to a natural refinement of Q1.

To wit, let me say that a monoid $H$ is *weakly [aperiodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_semigroup)* if the period of every $x \in H$ is either $1$ or $\infty$ (the period of $x$ is the infimum of the set of all $r \in \mathbf N^+$ for which there exists $m \in \mathbf N^+$ with $x^m = x^{m+r}$, with the convention that $\inf \emptyset := \infty$). Then we may ask the following:

> **Q2.** Given a non-trivial, weakly aperiodic, commutative, reduced monoid $K$ with an absorbing element, does there exist a commutative monoid $H$ such that $\mathcal I(H)$ is isomorphic to $K$? Has this realization problem been ever considered?

It's quite possible that further restrictions are needed for a realization result along these lines to be possible, but I don't have clear ideas about it right now.

*Edit 3 (Apr 27, 2017).* Also Q2 has a negative answer, as it is seen from the comments to  [Benjamin Steinberg's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/268125/16537).

Comment: Hi Salvo. As a newcomer to this thread, it's very hard to follow, because of the edits to the question in response to a commentary discussion on Benjamin Steinberg's answer. If there are further things you want to know, I suggest you ask them as a separate question.

Comment: Hi David. I get your point, and yes, I could (and should) have arranged things in a different way: I'll edit for one last time to make it clearer, I hope, that both questions in the OP have been answered in the negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. The problem is that $I^k\subseteq  I^{k-1}$ so no element can generate a cyclic group of order 2 as a subsemigroup. So take $Z/2$ and adjoin a zero and a new identity and you can't realize it.

Comment: Right! And this suggests an obvious refinement of the original question, so let me edit the OP.

Comment: There are other restrictions. Your monoid admits a compatible partial order with the identity the biggest element. This forces divisibility to be a partial order. In fact your monoid has arbitrary joins  in the order and the product distributes over the join.  So you have a commutative quantale with identity as the top. To be the multiplicative reductive of such a thing is very special.

Comment: I've *just* noted your comment (I was editing the OP while you were posting it). Let me try to think if your further remarks provide a negative answer also to Q2. Btw, do you know of any conventional name for what I'm provisionally calling a "totally acyclic monoid" in the OP?

Comment: On a second thought, I've just realized that $\mathcal I(H)$ is strongly unit-cancellative (https://mathoverflow.net/a/259790/16537), and so is, much more in general, the set $\mathcal I_r(H)$ of all $r$-ideals of $H$, equipped with the operation $\cdot_r$ of $r$-multiplication, where $r$ is a weak ideal system on $H$ (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267943/): It is enough to observe that $I\cdot_r J \subseteq I \cap J$ for all $I,J \in \mathcal I_r(H)$.

Comment: Now, the divisibility preorder of a strongly unit-cancellative, commutative monoid $H$ is always a (compatible) order: If $x, y \in H$, then $x \mid_H y$ and $y \mid_H x$ imply $x = ax$ for some $a \in H$ (here we use that $H$ is commutative), and hence $a = 1_H$ (here we use that $H$ is strongly unit-cancellative). Moreover, a strongly unit-cancellative, commutative monoid doesn't embed (as a subsemigroup) any non-trivial, finite group. So being strongly unit-cancellative accounts for two of the main restrictions you are observing in your answer and comments: I've to think about the others.

Comment: Let's forget about the "totally acyclic" stuff (as it is superseded by the condition "being strongly unit-cancellative", or by the equivalent condition "being reduced and unit-cancellative"): I'm convinced that a reduced, unit-cancellative, commutative monoid with an absorbing element need not be realizable as the monoid of ideals (under set multiplication) of a commutative monoid. So I'm accepting your answer, but will edit the OP once more to summarize the conclusions so far.

Comment: Usually people call a monoid aperiodic if its only torsion is of the form $x^n=x^{n+1}$ but some people use the term combinatorial in the infinite case.  If 1 is the maximum element in a partially ordered monoid then $a=ubv$ implies $b\leq a$.  Thus divisibility is an order.  Quantales with 1 as a maximum element are called two-sided and have a number of properties so you should look at a quantale book to get more restrictions.

Comment: A commutative monoid can have idempotent ideals so why must it be unit-cancellative?  Take a  meet semilattice.  Every ideal is idempotent so satisfies $I^2=I$.

Comment: *Of course*, you're right: In a rush, I overlooked the case when $IJ = I \cap J$. So the correct conclusion would rather be that $\mathcal I(H)$ is a reduced monoid where the only elements of finite order are the idempotents. Btw, thanks for the pointers. As for the terminology, I've been using "aperiodic" to refer to a monoid which is *not* periodic in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_semigroup#Related_notions (so, a monoid where there exists at least one element of infinite order).

Comment: Aperiodic is different than periodic.  All finite semigroup theorist use aperiodic to mean a finite semigroup in which $x^n=x^{n+1}$ for some $n$.

Comment: You do still have divisibility is a partial order.  I gave the proof above.  That is a restriction.  It means you cannot have any subsemigroup that is a non-trivial group.

Comment: As for the the use of "aperiodic": That's good to know! I will have to fix this detail in my scribbles. But then how would you call a semigroup where there is at least one element of infinite order? Simply "non-periodic" or "non-torsion"? This has not much to do with the thread, but since we are already there, I profit from this opportunity to ask. As for the divisibility: Sure.

Comment: I would say non-periodic or non-torsion. I think the term periodic was popular in the Soviet Union and the term torsion among the West.  The term aperiodic was decided on by French and American mathematicians I think.

Comment: I will go for non-torsion, thanks for this too!

Comment: As for "If $1$ is the max element in an ordered monoid then $a=ubv$ implies $b\le a$", shouldn't we rather assume $1_H$ is the *min* element? *Proof.* Let $(H,\le)$ be an ordered monoid s.t. $1_H\le x$ for all $x$, and pick $a,b\in H$ s.t. $b\mid_Ha$, i.e., $a=ubv$ for some $u,v\in H$. Since $1_H\le u,v$ and the order is compatible with the operation, we get $b=1_Hb1_H\le ubv=a$. [] On the other hand, the order we may want to put on $\mathcal I(H)$ is actually the one induced by $\supseteq$, and the min wrt $\supseteq$ is the max wrt to $\subseteq$, so there is no real issue.

Comment: Sorry I was writing quickly and got it reversed.  If 1 is max, then $b$ divides $a$ implies $a\leq b$.

Comment: No problem. On the other hand, I made more than one mistake with my statement that $\mathcal I(H)$ is unit-cancellative: This is *never* the case (unless we change a little bit the definitions to account for the case of monoids with an absorbing element), because $\emptyset \in \mathcal I(H)$ and $\mathcal I(H)$ is non-trivial. But, on a positive note, not all evil comes to harm: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268440/.